# What does the “l” in “Christkindl” mean?

Tags: suffix, bavarian, diminutive

What does the letter *l* at the end of the word *Christkindl* mean? My understanding is that the English *child* translates to the German *Kind.* Does the *l* make the word diminutive? When is it appropriate to add the *l* to a German noun?

Comment: Christkind-l(ein)  Note that the short form(s) are regional only!

Comment: I am working on an Austrian recipe called Apfel Radeln in an Austrian cookbook and found other versions online, so someone found a way to add a diminutive to Rad! Well, it`s suitable since the 'wheels' are so small.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is a diminutive suffix used in Bavarian and perhaps some other south-German dialects. *Christkind* (without the -l) is perfectly fine German.

Comment: Compare *-le*, the Swabian diminutive suffix and *-(e)rl* in some regions of Austria / Southern Tyrol.

Comment: Note that one of the standard diminutive suffixes is *-lein*, so *-l* may be a diminutive version of the diminutive.

Comment: vgl. Hänsel und Gretel

Comment: @Stephie or *-la* in some areas of Franconia

Comment: And -li in Swiss German.

Comment: Note that while Christkind is perfectly fine German, it would be rather uncommon to say Christkindmarkt. I would use Christkindlmarkt instead.

Comment: @NePh: Agree that with the -markt, Christkindl- would be more common. But this might be because some of the most famous markets are in the south?

Comment: @user1583209 In the North we call it *Weihnachtsmarkt*. AFAIK, all *Christkindlmärkte* are in the South. See also: http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-5/f01b/

Comment: Christkind**l**, Osterhas**erl**, Nikolaus**i** :)

Comment: @Roland In the south-west we call it Weihnachtsmarkt as well. All the Christkindlmarkt I have ever heard of where in Bavaria or where at least trying to copy a bavarian style one (whatever that is).

Comment: @CarstenS Allerdings sind Hans und Grete nicht ohnehin schon als klein zu erkennen. Man fragt sich, wieso ein Kind noch verkleinert werden muss. Ist es regional üblich mit Kindl Kleinkinder und Säuglinge zu bezeichnen?

Answer (score 5):

»Christkindl« is a diminutive of »Christkind«.

---

German has lots of regional differences (it is a [pluricentric language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluricentric_language#German)), and the grammar of diminutives is one aspect of German language, that varies over the regions.

The suffix ***-chen*** is valid everywhere where people speak German:

> Der Sack - das Säck**chen**
>   The bag - the small bag
>
> Das Kind - das Kind**chen**
>   the child - the small child

This works for almost all nouns and it is standard everywhere. Add the suffix *-chen* and sometimes change a vowel in the stem to an umlaut. No matter what gender the word was before, the diminutive is always neuter. (This is true for all kinds of German diminutives.)

Also ***-lein*** works everywhere and is everywhere standard

> Der Sack - das Säck**lein**
>   The bag - the small bag
>
> Das Kind - das Kind**lein**
>   the child - the small child

---

But in regions where a Bavarian dialect is spoken, there is an alternative ways to build a diminutive:

> Der Sack - das Sack**erl**
>   The bag - the small bag
>
> Das Kind - das Kind**erl**
>   the child - the small child

Notice, that some words, build by this pattern, are part of standard Austrian German (i.e. not dialect words). Examples are *Sackerl* (see above) and *Krügerl* (a jug for 0.5 liter beer). But no word ending with the Bavarian diminutive *-erl* is part of standard German German.
But »*Kinderl*« has dialect-status in all standard variations of German (also in standard Austrian German).

---

In Switzerland and Swabia you will find ***-li*** and ***-le*** as diminutive-suffixes:

> Der Sack - das Säck**li**
>   The bag - the small bag
>
> Das Kind - das Kind**le**
>   the child - the small child

---

There is also the one-letter-suffix ***-l*** as you found it in »Kindl« or »Christkindl«. It is a short version of ***-erl***, ***-li*** and ***-le*** and is not part of any standard variation.

Answer (score 2):

The final *-l* is indeed a diminutive. The non-diminuted version is simply *Christkind* as the other answer says and is easily understood by translating.

The diminutive final *-l* is Bavarian and an alternate form of the more common Bavarian diminutive *-erl.* Depending on the consonant sound that preceeds the diminutive, either one of the two may be preferred. For example, it is reasonably common to say *Kindl* even when not referring to the *Christkindl:* the person on Munich’s coat of arms is called the *Münchner Kindl.* For a word such as *Haus,* both *Heisl* and *Heiserl* are acceptable diminutives. For *Ball,* which already ends in *l,* adding another *-l* would not create an audible difference hence the diminutive would commonly be *Ballerl.* I’m sure there are beter examples that are escaping my thoughts at the moment.

Sometimes, the ending that looks like a diminutive is actually no longer perceived as one. One example from Austrian German would be *Sackerl* which translates into *Tüte* or *Tasche* in German German. A different example is the Bavarian word *Radl* meaning *bicycle.* The latter applies to all kinds, shapes and sizes and allows a distinction between a wheel *(Rad)* and a bicycle *(Radl).* While *Radl* is no longer perceived as a diminutive, it cannot acquire another diminutive ending; the only way to say *small bicycle* is to indeed say *kleines Radl.* On the other hand, *Hochradl* or *riesiges Radl* are no problem semantically.

Both *-erl* and *-l* are closely related to corresponding diminutives of neighbouring dialects: Swabian *-le,* Swiss *-li* and Franconian *-la.* Indeed, I have heard Swabians say *Christkindle* and Franconians say *Chistkindla.* Probably the only reason why I haven’t yet heard any Swiss say *Christchindli* (assuming that the *k* is modified as usually in Swiss dialects) is because I don’t know any Swiss.

Answer (score 0):

One original diminutive of Kind is *"Kindlein."* (There are others such as Kinderl.)

So "Kindl" is an abbreviation of one of the other diminutives that is a abbreviation of a diminutive.